# In Windows, how to get a standard device handle for a different console process?

Tags: windows, winapi, console, io-redirection

I know I can call the `AttachConsole` and  `GetStdHandle` kernel32 functions to access the console screen buffers of a different console process, but if this process has its input/output/error redirected to a file or device, how can I get handles to those redirected locations instead?

To put it clear: I don't have control on the application I'm trying to attach to, which is provided by a third party, so my chances with IPC are little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GetStdHandle` will honour any redirection and return the [redirected handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683231%28v=vs.85%29.aspx);

> The standard handles of a process may be redirected by a call to
>   `SetStdHandle`, in which case `GetStdHandle` *returns the redirected
>   handle*.

The link also describes how to request the originals.

Comment: I realize the process I'm attaching to internally overwrites the standard output specified in the command line.

Comment: But, `GetStdHandle` returns redirection only for process, where function is calling. It can't return valid value for external process (IPC mentioned in Q.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `CreateRemoteThread` to insert code into the other process and call `GetStdHandle` from there.  You'll then need to use `DuplicateHandle` to make a copy of the handle in your own process.

Keep in mind that anything you do with that handle will affect the handle in the target process, which could cause unexpected problems.  If both processes attempt to read from the standard input stream, for example, you won't be able to predict which one will see what part of the input, and if both processes write to the standard output stream the output might be overlapped in random ways or one set of output might overwrite the other.

Comment: The caveat is that `DuplicateHandle` cannot duplicate unredirected console handles for another process: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682075(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @ft1: Thanks.  I didn't know that.  What's the best way to check for this?  GetFileType?

Comment: Well, in the doc about WriteConsole they recommend checking if GetConsoleMode succeeds, but I haven't tested it yet, so don't trust me more than MSDN :-)